# Android: Replacing of fragment removes other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use android support library and i have 3 fragments on activity.
And i have a problem: **replacing of fragment removes other fragment**

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Add 3 fragments:

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container1, new A(), A.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container2, new B(), B.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container3, new C(), C.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.test) {

            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentByTag(A.class.getCanonicalName());
            if (fragment == null)
                fragment = new A();

            // Replace fragment A again
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container1, fragment, fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName())
                        .commit();
            // After this fragment B disappears


            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I use findFragmentByTag to avoid memory leak.
Can you help me?

Comment: Try adding this to the fragment transaction, before commit
`// Add this transaction to the back stack
.addToBackStack()`

Comment: Not sure your question is clear, because you do .replace so as expected the previous fragment is replaced. Now as @IonutNegru says if the problem is that you can not go backward then use addToBackStack, but the question is not clear.

Comment: @HpTerm is also right, you should use add to avoid the replace of current fragment. I missed that one.
You can check the official documentation for fragments. There are some examples for your case also.

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);  
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Try this code to replace any fragment

Answer (score 0):

## try this way:

make a common mathod to add fragments in your container,just put this code to your method and pass your fragment in that mehod,like:

```
public void _LoadFragment(Fragment _frag){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, _frag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Add 3 fragments:

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container1, new A(), A.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container2, new B(), B.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container3, new C(), C.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.test) {

            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentByTag(A.class.getCanonicalName());
            if (fragment == null)
                fragment = new A();

            // Replace fragment A again

            // After this fragment B disappears
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
             fragmentTransaction.commit();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Try this